# Can' call XSP functions in XPINC

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpinc

I try to call `XSP._isDirty()` for XPINC but it does not work. In the browser everything works fine. Is there a trick how i can use it.

Is there a way how i can see clientside errors when i'm executing XPages in the Notesclient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two questions here.

### Q1. XSP._isDirty()

XSP._isDirty() is an internal call. From the XPages portable command guide (page 156).

> XSP._isDirty() : Used internally by the Dirty Save feature— see the `<xp:view>` properties for `enableModifiedFlag`. This is a private function.

Code for this call is in the file `xspClientDojo.js` (look for the uncompressed file on Domino/Notes).

As it is an internal call it is used at risk. There is no guarantee it will work as expected in later versions.

The `enableModifiedFlag` is an XPage attribute that allows you to mark the page as dirty and prevent the user accidentally leaving the page. There are more details about this on the [Infocenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_pref_enablemodifiedflag.html).

### Q2. Client side debugging.

You can review client side errors using the developer panel of most modern browsers, or something like the [firebug plugin](http://getfirebug.com). The XPages extension library comes with a [Firebug Lite](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8GS9DC) component you can use as well.

For SSJS and XSP engine issues you can review these in the Notes client by reading the XPages logs in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder contained in the Notes data folder.

For a "live" method of this is to modify the shortcut that launches notes as follows:

```
Target: C:\Lotus\Notes\notes.exe -RPARAMS -console -debug -separateSysLogFiles -consoleLog
Start In : C:\Lotus\Notes\framework\
```

Change the path to match your clients install.

Comment: 1. i'm not sure. does that mean i can't use it for xpinc? And if not is there maybe another solution to see if the document is dirty? 2. Works great, thanks

Comment: I just realized that the debug mode only logs SSJS or Java errors. Is there also a way to see the client-side-script errors?

Comment: OK I misunderstood exactly what you wanted on Q2. So I've updated my answer for both your comments.